# Responsive HTML5 web page: What is best practice?

Tags: html, responsive-design

I'm working on creating Responsive web page using HTML5. Inside HTML5 Head tag, I've title, meta and link tags, is there any recommended best practice for sequencing these tags to get best possible results ? Current structure of the my page is mentioned below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-saleable=false;"/>
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>
<title>Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
Content 
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please suggest, if there is any best practice I need to follow, to utilize HTML5 in best possible way for responsive page design?

Comment: doesn't seem like this question belongs here, but i think the way you wrote it is fine. but maybe: `user-saleable=false` should be changed, i think the user should be able to sell your page

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok but:

1. Responsive web design has nothing whatsoever to do with HTML5.
2. You shouldn't set maximum-scale nor user-scaleable (which you've got a typo in) to false as the user should be able to scale and zoom in if they want/need to.
3. Remove the xmlns stuff, it's not needed.
4. Don't use inline styles in elements, it's not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

This library is very useful to design responsive template

http://getbootstrap.com/